# Валидация отвечающей определённому шаблону строки установленной длины

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет! Задание по регулярке: Должно быть от 3 до 30 символов, разрешены только буквы и ОДИН знак "*" в любом месте. Мои решения:

```
/^(?=.{3,30}$)([a-zA-Z]+\*?)$/
/^(?=.{3,30}$)(\*?[a-zA-Z]+\*?[a-zA-Z]+\*?)$/
```

Ну как Вы понимаете это не правильно. Помогите решить.

Answer (score 6):

```
/^(?=.{3,30}$)[a-zA-Z]*\*?[a-zA-Z]*$/
```

Тест на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Axr1s1/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее оптимальный способ — проверить длину строки с помощью блока просмотра вперёд (как в оригинальном выражении), а потом найти 0+ букв после которых следует опциональная последовательность обязательного знака `*` и снова 0+ букв:

```
/^(?=.{3,30}$)[a-zA-Z]*(?:\*[a-zA-Z]*)?$/
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/1OzTkG/1).

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?=.{3,30}$)` - с начала строки и до конца должно быть от 3 до 30 любых символов, отличных от символов перевода на новую строку
- `[a-zA-Z]*` - 0 или более ASCII-букв
- `(?:\*[a-zA-Z]*)?` - 1 или 0 повторов

  - `\*` - символ `*`
  - `[a-zA-Z]*` - 0 или более ASCII-букв
- `$` - конец строки.

```js
var strs = ['abcXYZ','abc*XYZ','*abcXYZ', 'abcXYZ*','*abcXYZ*','abc**XYZ', 'a*bcXY*Z', '', 'a', 'ab'];
var rx = /^(?=.{3,30}$)[a-zA-Z]*(?:\*[a-zA-Z]*)?$/;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```

Comment: зачем усложнять если можно просто
`^(?=.{3,30})[a-zA-Z]*\*?[a-zA-Z]*$`

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей Это не принципиально, проблема здесь другая. Кроме того, незахватывающие группы очень удобны, этот шаблон легко изменить так, чтобы разрешить `*` только между буквами, заменив `*` на `+`.